# Percentage loading indicator that represents function or thread processing state

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

**Problem:** When a function is called, google popup says "Running script blahblah" with cancel, dismiss buttons. This green popup gets dismissed after a while(when?), but many cells still show Loading.. state and values are still being populated, meaning the functions are still being run.

**Requirement:** Need information on some sort of indicator, spinning circle/loading ui or just a simple percentage wise indication of how much processing/function calls have been done, or something that gives the user some indication as to how much loading left, or when it finishes. I realise I'm being vague because I'm unsure if this sort of process monitoring function exists. I visualise it like a thread monitor, that goes green when all processing is complete. But a cell populated with 0-100% value will also do.

**Context:** When I click on a button, my code executes a lot of functions on a vast range of cells, which require a considerable amount of processing time even with optimisations, during which the state of many cells remain as "Loading..".   After all functions have been executed, and all cells have been populated, only then, the user needs to perform some manual inspection/other activities. But there is no indication given to the user that all processing has been completed, other than manual scrolling and searching for absence of "Loading" indicator in all cells, which is tedious.

**Alternative Solutions** (in case there is no direct processing indicator function):

1. Callback or return some value for every function, and validate if all of them have arrived (not feasible I feel, coz the number of times a single function has to be executed changes with user specified input ex: user gives 3 inputs, function executes for 300 cells. Also as explained before, the cell population/Loading state happens even after apparent function execution end)
2. Function to scan the page for cell display value of "Loading.." and if none, indicate that loading has been completed (This function doesn't work as expected, I'm guessing some sync issues) I know this is most feasible option but I was really looking forward to some kind of value/function that automatically tells me that processing is done.

I don't think code snippet is required for this, as I'm basically asking if a particular feature exists or not. If not, alternatives would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach is to display a loading-icon after a button is clicked. My recommendation is something like [MaterializeCSS](https://materializecss.com/preloader.html).

I assume there are 2 files:

1. Front-End HTML which contains the View
2. Back-End Apps Script File which contains Controller

So in your File #1 you would add the following loading bar:

```
<!-- this is your existing button -->
<button id="yourTriggerButton">Click here</button>

<!-- in your css file, add #loadingBar{display:none} so that is hidden by default -->
<div class="progress" id="loadingBar">
  <div class="indeterminate"></div>
</div>

// we can also add some output message here
<div id="outputDiv"></div>
```

And at the bottom of your front-end file, within a `script` tag we state that we want to show the loading element wenn the button is clicked (and your back-end script is running) and the hide it once the process is finished:

```
const triggerButton = document.getElementById("yourTriggerButton");  
const loadingElement = document.getElementById("loadingBar");
const outputElement = document.getElementById("outputDiv");   

triggerButton.addEventListener( "click", function(e){
  // lets show the loading icon when clicked
  loadingElement.style.display = "block";
  google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(handleSuccess)
    .backEndFunction()

  // this is called once backEndFunction is finished / returned
  function handleSuccess( returnValueFromBackEnd ){
    // lets hide the loading icon
    loadingElement.style.display = "none";
    // and show the user some feedback
    outputElement.innerText = "Done processing…"; // or you can input something that is returned from the back-end function
  }

});
```

Comment: This looks like a neat solution. BUT, I don't have an html front end, all my code is run on the .gs files, and the output I want is on the spreadsheet itself as a cell value. Is there anyway I can call google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(handleSuccess) or something similar within a Google Sheets .gs file? I can just make handleSuccess function to output "Done processing" as a cell value, but I see that we cant access google.script.run in .gs